# android: SQLite query returns no results

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am building an Android app that uses a SQLite database.
For this one task I have to run a query that looks like this:

```
 SELECT item.id, item.price, t1.quantity
 FROM item, (SELECT id, price
            FROM list
            WHERE list.state = 'sold') t1
 WHERE item.id = t1.id
```

So far, I have tried:

```
Cursor c = resolver.query(uriRawQuery, null, selection, null, null)
```

where `uriRawQuery` is used to tell the `ContentProvider` that it should perform a `db.rawQuery(selection, null)` and `selection` is a string similar to the query above.

The problem is no data is returned into the `Cursor`. When I call `c.moveToFirst()` I get `false`.

**The weird thing is that if I open the database file in SQLite Manager and run the exact same query I get results.**

I know I can modify the query to make a join between the original `list` and `item` tables but I find it to be less efficient that way.

Any ideas would be very appreciated as I have spent too man hours on this already.

**EDIT**

I know what a `join` is, what I said is that it is a lot more efficient if I do it like this instead of using the entire `list` table.

**I forgot a very important aspect**
The `WHERE` clause looks like

```
" WHERE list.state = 'sold' and list.name like '" + arg + "%'"
```

where `arg` is a string.

Comment: Actually, using a join will be more efficient

Comment: You are already using a join. The comma (`,`) in this context is actually a join operator according to SQLite. You may as well make the join explicit.

Comment: Post your code where you create and pass query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, I still don't know why this was happening but at least I got the `Cursor` to actually select the rows.

After many trials I thought about ditching the  syntax above and write this instead:

```
" WHERE list.state = 'sold' and list.name like ? "
```

and move the argument in

```
selectionArgs = new String[]{arg + "%"}
```

I am going to wait a while before accepting the answer, in case someone provides an explanation as to why even though both queries look exactly the same they get different results.